# JS: Alter Color for specific image in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawing

Let say I got the sprite to the left and I want to apply a red filter over the image before drawing it in a canvas so it looks like the sprite to the right. http://puu.sh/6dQ0E.png

Is there a way to do that?
It could be done in two steps, but I don't know if it's possible to draw the geometric figure that has the exact same shape than the image. (Ex: Drawing a rectangle over it won't match.)

Note: I want the filter to only be applied to this image, not the whole canvas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine 2 filtering operations to draw the red filter only on top of your existing sprite.

**globalCompositeOperation**="source-atop" will cause new drawings to only draw on top of existing non-transparent pixels.

**globalAlpha** will make your new drawings semi-transparent.

Taken together, you can draw a semi-transparent filter that only fills where your non-transparent ghost exsits.

Then just draw a red rectangle over your existing sprite (the rectangle will only be visible inside the existing ghost).

[image]

```
ctx.drawImage(ghostSprites,0,0);
ctx.globalAlpha=0.62;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-atop";
ctx.fillStyle="red";
ctx.fillRect(spriteX,spriteY,spriteWidth,spriteHeight);
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/W4XrG/

**From here...**

Notice the black outlines of your sprite become washed from the red filter.

You could also use context.getImageData to grab only the black pixels of your ghost.  Then redraw those black pixels over your red-filtered ghost so the black outlines are not washed.  If you feel ambitious, you could give that a try!

Good luck with your project!

Here’s code

```
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; padding:20px;}
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img=new Image();
    img.onload=start;
    img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
    img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/temp0a.png";
    function start(){}

    var spriteX=0;
    var spriteY=0;
    var spriteWidth=133;
    var spriteHeight=161

    $("#recolor").click(function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        ctx.globalAlpha=0.62;
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation="source-atop";
        ctx.fillStyle="red";
        ctx.fillRect(spriteX,spriteY,spriteWidth,spriteHeight);
    });

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>Before</p>
    <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/stackoverflow/temp0a.png">
    <p>After</p>
    <button id="recolor">Click to recolor the green sprite</button><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=161></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if there is already something on my canvas (ex: a map) and I'm drawing this image over it? Does that mean I'd to create a new canvas over the canvas for the map in order for source-atop to work?

Comment: Yes, before your games starts you would red-filter your ghost on the spritesheet, not after it’s on the canvas.  Save your red-ghost as a separate image for use in your game.